# Como faço para desmarcar o radio button anterior após selecionar outro?

Tags: html, formulário, validação, radiobutton

Tenho cinco `radio button`, destes cinco um encontra-se "marcado", como eu faço para desmarcar o `radio button` que eu cliquei após clicar em outro?

**Exemplo:**

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>Selecione:</legend>
  <label>Morango:
   <input type="radio" id="A" checked/>
  </label>
  <label>Maracujá: 
   <input type="radio" id="B" />
  </label>
  <label>Melancia:
   <input type="radio" id="C" />
  </label>
  <label>Melão: 
    <input type="radio" id="D" />
  </label>
  <label>Mamão:
    <input type="radio" id="E" />
  </label>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: defina o mesmo name

Comment: após isso, coloque sua própria resposta ;)

Comment: por exemplo: name="radio-btn"

Comment: @MuriloGambôa Grato pela dica! Era um detalhe que desconhecia, agora entendo que sem definir a tag `name` o `checked` fica pra toda coleção `radio`.

Comment: Uma pergunta muito semelhante: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/418763/como-fa%c3%a7o-para-desmarcar-o-radio-button-que-%c3%a9-ligado-a-outro-anterior-ap%c3%b3s-selec

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Se você definir o conteudo do atributo `name` aos inputs de forma identica.
Ex: `name="myGroup"`, por padrão você terá o comportamento desejado.

Segue abaixo

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>Selecione:</legend>
  <label>Morango:
   <input type="radio" id="A" name="myGroup"/>
  </label>
  <label>Maracujá: 
   <input type="radio" id="B" name="myGroup" />
  </label>
  <label>Melancia:
   <input type="radio" id="C" name="myGroup" />
  </label>
  <label>Melão: 
    <input type="radio" id="D" name="myGroup" />
  </label>
  <label>Mamão:
    <input type="radio" id="E" name="myGroup" />
  </label>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: André Paulo, Valeu! Tai um detalhe que nunca parei pra pensar o que realmente era que fazia o "checked" ir para outro `radio button`. E o pior que foi um vacilo meu mesmo, pois estava funcionando perfeitamente num projeto pessoal, que estou desenvolvendo. Dai decidi remover os `name`, e começou a minha corrida contra o tempo pra descobrir o que havia dado errado que todos estavam ficando selecionado. Ja cansado de procurar entender resolvi Perguntar. :D